# Can we convert asymmetrical XML file to a symmetrical one using Python?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I have a really big XML file with the following structure:

```xml
<file>
  <fields>
    <lastname>LASTNAME1</lastname>
    <name>NAME1</name>
    <id>ID1</id>
    <wage>WAGE1</wage>
    <another-price>PRICE1</another-price>
    <method>METHOD1</method>
  </fields>
  <fields>
    <lastname>LASTNAME2</lastname>
    <name>NAME2</name>
    <id>ID2</id>
    <another-price>PRICE2</another-price>
    <method>METHOD2</method>
  </fields>
  <fields>
    <lastname>LASTNAME3</lastname>
    <id>ID3</id>
    <wage>WAGE3</wage>
    <another-price>PRICE3</another-price>
  </fields>
</file>
```

As you can see in this dummy data first field has all fields with a value, on the other hand second field is missing wage field and also the third one is missing both name and method fields. I'm using another Python code to convert all these in a table making the field names column names and the data as their row data. But when my XML is missing any fields my original loop can't keep track of column names and it just adds second field's another price data to wage column for example. I think I managed to explain my situation.

I tried like grouping by those field names within the code but I couldn't succeed it, so I thought of a solution like if there is a code that can convert my XML to symmetrical XML file with null values (or anything really) I'd stop encountering this issue. Waiting to hear your suggestions and solutions!

Comment: Do you know the complete list of valid field names ahead of time?

Comment: @JonSG I can have the complete list for sure, can not think/find a solution at the moment so if you can think of anything with the list of field names that'd be a step closer for me!

Comment: You should be able to handle the missing fields. Can you give us an example fo what you are doing now?

Comment: @JonSG For my example in the main question I have 6 fields, but per se I don't know how can I input <wage></wage> into the second field if it doesn't exist. If someone can help me with that I'd be able to solve rest of my problems I believe.

Comment: @EdizGörkemAkıncı what should be the output of your code?

Comment: @balderman so basically I extract this data to Alteryx Designer using python's findall() from their paths. But my XML data is structured like the example above (actually it's even worse). But I basically want every parent node and their all possible fields (even if they have empty data or missing fields within that parent node) in a table format. I'm trying to accomplish this for 2 days in a row now and I can't get anything to work.

Comment: @EdizGörkemAkıncı I think I solved your problem. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below (the idea is to build a set of fields first)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<file>
  <fields>
    <lastname>LASTNAME1</lastname>
    <name>NAME1</name>
    <id>ID1</id>
    <wage>WAGE1</wage>
    <another-price>PRICE1</another-price>
    <method>METHOD1</method>
  </fields>
  <fields>
    <lastname>LASTNAME2</lastname>
    <name>NAME2</name>
    <id>ID2</id>
    <another-price>PRICE2</another-price>
    <method>METHOD2</method>
  </fields>
  <fields>
    <lastname>LASTNAME3</lastname>
    <id>ID3</id>
    <wage>WAGE3</wage>
    <another-price>PRICE3</another-price>
  </fields>
</file>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
fields_set = set()
fields_list = root.findall('.//fields')
for fields_entry in fields_list:
    for field in fields_entry:
        fields_set.add(field.tag)
print(f'fields set: {fields_set}')
for fields_entry in fields_list:
    data = {}
    for field in fields_set:
        element = fields_entry.find(field)
        value = element.text if element is not None else 'N/A'
        data[field] = value
    print(data)
```

output

```
fields set: {'another-price', 'name', 'id', 'lastname', 'wage', 'method'}
{'another-price': 'PRICE1', 'name': 'NAME1', 'id': 'ID1', 'lastname': 'LASTNAME1', 'wage': 'WAGE1', 'method': 'METHOD1'}
{'another-price': 'PRICE2', 'name': 'NAME2', 'id': 'ID2', 'lastname': 'LASTNAME2', 'wage': 'N/A', 'method': 'METHOD2'}
{'another-price': 'PRICE3', 'name': 'N/A', 'id': 'ID3', 'lastname': 'LASTNAME3', 'wage': 'WAGE3', 'method': 'N/A'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use pandas, you get None only:

```
import pandas as pd

xml="""<file>
  <fields>
    <lastname>LASTNAME1</lastname>
    <name>NAME1</name>
    <id>ID1</id>
    <wage>WAGE1</wage>
    <another-price>PRICE1</another-price>
    <method>METHOD1</method>
  </fields>
  <fields>
    <lastname>LASTNAME2</lastname>
    <name>NAME2</name>
    <id>ID2</id>
    <another-price>PRICE2</another-price>
    <method>METHOD2</method>
  </fields>
  <fields>
    <lastname>LASTNAME3</lastname>
    <id>ID3</id>
    <wage>WAGE3</wage>
    <another-price>PRICE3</another-price>
  </fields>
</file>"""

df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath='.//fields')
print(df)
```

output:

```
    lastname   name   id   wage another-price   method
0  LASTNAME1  NAME1  ID1  WAGE1        PRICE1  METHOD1
1  LASTNAME2  NAME2  ID2   None        PRICE2  METHOD2
2  LASTNAME3   None  ID3  WAGE3        PRICE3     None
```

Comment: I can't get pandas to work with read_xml, tried everything and updated pandas as well. Do you might have any other suggestions?

Comment: Hey so I did manage to work pandas with the file that I have and it's looking promising for sure. But I do have one problem, imagine the whole XML file continues even after <fields>....</fields> and it goes on with another parent node like <fields2>...</fields2> and even <fieldsx></fieldsx>...

Would it be possible to make something like take all the parent nodes under <file> (the root) tag?

Comment: @EdizGörkemAkıncı, this should work in your explained case: `df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath='*') `

Answer (score 0):

A simple transformation in XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:template match="fields">
  <fields>
    <lastname>{lastname}</lastname>
    <name>{name}</name>
    <id>{id}</id>
    <wage>{wage}</wage>
    <another-price>{another-price}</another-price>
    <method>{method}</method>
  </fields>
</xsl:template>
```

In earlier versions of XSLT (such as the default processor bundled with Python) replace `{name}` by `<xsl:value-of select="name"/>`.

Comment: Tried doing it but it didn't work for me, it only gave me the field names which I have already, can you elaborate more on what I should do with this?

Comment: Sorry, I should have remembered that the curly braces require XSLT 3.0. I'll qualify the answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to go through your input data and set the missing values.
Something like this:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("data.xml")
required_fields = [
    "lastname", "name", "id", "another-price", "method", "wage"
]

for user in tree.xpath("/file/fields"):
for field in required_fields:
    if not user.xpath(field):
        new_field = etree.SubElement(user, field)
        new_field.text = "None"

a = etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
print(a.decode())
```

Would output something like this:

```
<file>
<fields>
<lastname>LASTNAME1</lastname>
<name>NAME1</name>
<id>ID1</id>
<wage>WAGE1</wage>
<another-price>PRICE1</another-price>
<method>METHOD1</method>
</fields>
<fields>
<lastname>LASTNAME2</lastname>
<name>NAME2</name>
<id>ID2</id>
<another-price>PRICE2</another-price>
<method>METHOD2</method>
<wage>None</wage>
</fields>
<fields>
<lastname>LASTNAME3</lastname>
<id>ID3</id>
<wage>WAGE3</wage>
<another-price>PRICE3</another-price>
<name>None</name>
<method>None</method>
</fields>
</file>
```